# Debug log the text returned via tex.sprint() and friends?

Tags: luatex, debugging

Is there an easy way to see what text was sent from Lua to TeX via `tex.sprint()`, `tex.print()`, and `tex.write()`?  (e.g., print it to stdout or log it to the `.log` file)

Comment: Why not just use a wrapper that calls ``print()`` or ``io.write()`` on the strings if some trace flag is set?

Comment: @phg I'm not very familiar with Lua—can I replace `tex.print()` with the wrapper so that it works with 3rd party LuaTeX code that I use in my document?

Comment: Not in all cases. Because of its efficiency, it is idiomatic in Lua to use local references to functions instead of calling them explicitly. Consequently, after a chunk of code (e.g. a ``.lua`` file) is loaded those references are fixed and cannot be replaced. Not without resorting to the *debug* library anyways. You’d have to substitute your wrappers *before* loading third party code.
This should be possible but make sure you get the semantics right. If you intend to use Context it might not work at all because most Lua libraries are loaded before the document gets to execute anything.